# String blit fails with error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type bytes

Tags: ocaml

While trying to compile the following expression :

```
String.blit (String.make tfs.len ' ') 0 tfs.txt 0 tfs.len;
```

the compiler complains with the following error :

```
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type bytes
and the variable 'tfs.txt' (of type string) is pointed at.
```

As suggested in some forum, I tried to set the variable `OCAMLPARAM` to the value: `safe_string=0,_`
but with no result

I'm using OCaml 4.11.1 under Ubuntu 20.01.01 LTS

Comment: From [the documentation](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/String.html): "Note: OCaml strings used to be modifiable in place, for instance via the String.set and String.blit functions described below. This usage is only possible when the compiler is put in "unsafe-string" mode by giving the -unsafe-string command-line option. This compatibility mode makes the types string and bytes (see module Bytes) interchangeable so that functions expecting byte sequences can also accept strings as arguments and modify them."

Comment: Since this is an intentional breaking change, and the ability to use `unsafe-string` is intended to be removed in the future, I would strongly recommend against using it.

Answer (score 5):

Since OCaml 4.10.0, the distinction between immutable `string` and mutable `bytes` is a configure-time default that cannot be changed on a program-by-program basis.

If you are trying to compile some old legacy code, it might make sense to use a version of OCaml configured without this distinction.

Otherwise, it would be more future-proof to adapt your code to use `bytes` when in-place mutation of strings is needed (which is not clear from your code snippet).

Comment: Thanks, I've modified the program to avoid editing the string 'in place'